# Removing property inside observable array

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

If i define object like

```
var Person = function(id, name, country) {
    var self = this;
    self.id = ko.observable(id);
    self.name = ko.observable(name);
    self.country = ko.observable(country); 

    return self;
};
```

How can i remove property "country" from this object on click event of button. Thing is that when i send data to webservice i dont want to send this property to it.

Please see fiddle here where i am trying to remove property "country" on click event of save button.
http://jsfiddle.net/kirannandedkar/nZDrk/7/

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10048485/how-to-clear-remove-observable-bindings-in-knockout-js ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to delete this property from all objects:

```
this.SaveDetail = function() {
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(people(), function(item){
        delete item["country"];                 
    });
};
```

Here is working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nZDrk/8/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `delete` keyword to remove a property from an object entirely:

```
var somePerson = new Person(1, 'blah', 'blah');
delete somePerson.country;
// send somePerson to the webservice
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're sending the data to this webservice, what you should be doing is implementing the `toJSON()` function on your object and remove the property there.  Then send the result of calling `ko.toJSON()` on the model.  That way, your model still contains the property but what you send has the properties removed.

```
var Person = function(id, name, country) {
    var self = this;
    self.id = ko.observable(id);
    self.name = ko.observable(name);
    self.country = ko.observable(country); 

    self.toJSON = function () {
        var data = ko.toJS(self); // get the values of this model
        // delete the property from the data
        delete data.country;
        return data;
    };
};

var person = new Person(1, 'foo', 'bar');
var data = ko.toJSON(person); // {"id":1,"name":"foo"}
```