# How to remove bindings from node in knockout?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, knockout.js

I've found that in theory `ko.cleanNode()` should remove bindings from node if called, but in **[this example](http://jsfiddle.net/BrsmC/1/)** it doesn't seem to work.

**Javascript:**

```
// View model
var vm = {
    name: ko.observable("John")
}

// Node to be added
var node = $("<div/>",{
    id: "testing",
    'data-bind' : "text: name()"
});

// First addition to body
$("body").append(node);

// Apply bindings
ko.applyBindings(vm,$("#testing")[0]);

// Remove
ko.cleanNode($("#testing")[0]);

$("#testing").remove();

$("body").append(node);
```

**Result:** You can see in **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BrsmC/1/)** , that node still has attached binding (event listener).

Comment: Standard KO bindings don't track event listeners as such. `cleanNode` removes the "internal bindings". See http://stackoverflow.com/a/15069509/2246674 - I've found it best to simply play with KO as it wants to be played with.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Knockout is removing the knockout related bindings from the node, but when it does so, it does not reset the node to empty values. It just stops updating the node automatically from the viewmodel, vm.

http://jsfiddle.net/BrsmC/2/

Take out line 21 of the updated fiddle.

```
ko.cleanNode($("#testing")[0]);
```

You should see when you run it, the name is now 'imnotbinding'.

Comment: Does `cleanNode` work if passed an element that contains multiple, nested bindings, or does it require the node and binding itself?