# Bind modified in runtime viewmodel

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js

I've faced problem with binding modified at runtime viewmodel through prototype to particular html elements.
I've added an array to model, but after applying bindings - nothing happen. Added observables working fine, but problem exactly with arrays.

Here is a jsfiddle with code: [click](http://jsfiddle.net/pQQsY/46/)

```
var ViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    this.selectedItems = [{FullName: 'Mike'}]                                   
};
var model = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(model,document.getElementById('node'));
ko.cleanNode(document.getElementById('node'));
model.__proto__.items = [{FullName: 'Michael'}];
ko.applyBindings(model, document.getElementById('node'));
```

Thx for advice.

Comment: Regarding your fiddle... Did you mean $data.selectedItems instead of $.data.items?

Comment: $data.items - an array that added through __proto__

Comment: Apologies, but your question (what are you asking exactly? the code in your question does not really [repro](http://sscce.org) an issue) nor fiddle (second @veritasetratio's comment, and even then it does what I'd expect it to do) makes much sense. Could you please edit and clarify?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that ko.cleanNode is [not working as you think it is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15063794/can-cleannode-be-used-to-clean-binding).  It is not removing all of the bindings as you think it is.

I would recommend completely removing your node div, and then cloning and re-adding it.  Naturally jQuery makes this easy, if you happen to be using that.  Otherwise I would back up a bit and really evaluate whether you need to add things to a viewModel's prototype and then re-bind to your div.  Are you sure an `if` binding won't do what you want?

Also, consider testing this code with knockout 3 - I'm confident you'll get an error about applying bindings multiple times.

Comment: I cannot completely remove node div, because in my project I'm binding value to all page including page title, and some other places in head, so I cannot remove my HTML node ...

Comment: @coirius - then look at using an if binding to re-generate nodes.  Also note that you *can* remove a given node and then re-add it, and re-call applybindings to IT.  Or you can call applyBindingsToNode on it, and provide a root context.