# In knockout what is the significance of the index 0 in ko.cleanNode($element[0])

Tags: knockout.js

In knockout, I am using **ko.cleanNode($("#aDivInPartialView")[0])** to clean a node before applying binding second/multiple times because of change in view model occurred by drop down changes.
My question is why do I have to pass this index value and what is the significance of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ko.cleanNode is for internal use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15063794/can-cleannode-be-used-to-clean-binding#answer-15069509). Apart from that, the importance of the index is related to what `$element` is. Although [there is such a special variable](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html), it is used in the HTML, not in the JS. Most likely in your code it is the result of a [jQuery selector](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/), which returns a nodelist, and you want the first retrieved item.