# Not getting all values in View when binding children properties of observable

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js

In my knockout bound view I am not getting all values.

This is my script file:

```
var ViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.games = ko.observableArray();
    self.error = ko.observable();
    self.detail = ko.observable();

    var gamesUri = '/api/games/';

    self.getGameDetail = function (item) {
        ajaxHelper(gamesUri + item.Id, 'GET').done(function (data) {
            self.detail(data);
        });
        console.log(self.detail);
    };
    function ajaxHelper(uri, method, data) {
        self.error('');
        return $.ajax({
            type: method,
            url: uri,
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: data ? JSON.stringify(data) : null
        }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            self.error(errorThrown);
        });
    }

    function getAllGames() {
        ajaxHelper(gamesUri, 'GET').done(function (data) {
            self.games(data);
        });
    }

    getAllGames();
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

This is my view:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h2 class="panel-title">Games</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <ul class="list-unstyled" data-bind="foreach: games">
                <li>
                    <strong><span data-bind="text: DeveloperName"></span>:<span data-bind="text: Title"></span></strong>
                    <small><a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.getGameDetail">Details</a></small>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="alert alert-danger" data-bind="visible: error"><p data-bind="text: error"></p></div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
       <div class="panel panel-default">
           <div class="panel-heading"><h2 class="panel-title">Details</h2></div>
       </div>
        <table class="table">
            <tr><td>Developer</td><td data-bind="text: detail().DeveloperName"></td></tr> //Only this value is displayed
            <tr><td>Title</td><td data-bind="text: detail().Title"></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Price</td><td data-bind="text: detail().Price"></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Genre</td><td data-bind="text: detail().Genre"></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Year</td><td data-bind="text: detail().Year"></td></tr>
        </table>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">

    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is it only displays `DeveloperName` in the view. `Title`, `Price`, `Genre` and `Year` are not dispayed in the view. I tried many things but I don't know where the error is.

Comment: Do you get correct data from server? Any errors in the console debugger?

Comment: server is providing correct data. I checked it. But in browser i m not getting full data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two approaches.

The easiest one is to use the `with` or `template` binding. The technique is similar, but I'll show an example with the `with` binding:

```
<table class="table" data-bind="with: details">
   <tr><td>Developer</td><td data-bind="text: DeveloperName"></td></tr>
   <tr><td>Title</td><td data-bind="text: Title"></td></tr>
   <tr><td>Price</td><td data-bind="text: Price"></td></tr>
   <tr><td>Genre</td><td data-bind="text: Genre"></td></tr>
   <tr><td>Year</td><td data-bind="text: Year"></td></tr>
</table>
```

With this technique, whenever you change the object inside the `details` observable, the new values are applied to the children elements inside the elment which has the `with` binding. In this case all the elements inside the `table` element. Besides, the syntax is shorter and more clear. *NOTE: you must can use `$parent`, `$parents[]` or `$root` if you need to bind something outside the object bound with `with`.*

The hardest one, which is only neccessary if your viewmodel is more complex and has, for example, computed observables, you need to create an object whose properties are also observables. In this case you bind this object once, and, on the next occasions, you update the innser obervable properties, instead of changing the object itself.

For your example, you must create an object which has all its properties, like `DeveloperName`, `Title`, `Price`, etc. defined as observables. Then you must map the values recovered by AJAX to this properties, which you can do by hand, doing `details().DeveloperName(newDetails.DeveloperName)`, and so on, or using the [ko.mapping](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) plugin.

*Important note: if you use this technique you must keep the original `details` bound object, and update its properties. If you substitute the `details` object itself with a new one, the binding will be lost, and will stop working as desired.*

Another note: you cannot use cleanNodes for what you think. Please, see [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15063794/can-cleannode-be-used-to-clean-binding).