# HTML table not responding to Knockout binding

Tags: html, knockout.js, datatables-1.10

I have a set of parent and child objects which I am displaying in a table. 
[image]

The table DOM is wired to the model via Knockout. This works pretty well and the table changes whenever the model changes.

Now, applying `DataTable` to the table brings in some issues to the table. The view is no longer responding to Knockout bindings for some reason.

**You can see the problem illustrated in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rz09djdq/1/)**

Click on 'Clear families' nothing will happen. I was expecting the table to completely clear out.

**QUESTION**

Why is the DOM no longer responding to my model changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because once you initialize data table to the DOM, DataTables takes control of the table by cloning and adds a number of elements around the table to both control the table and show additional information about it. So whenever you clear your array in fact your `observableArray` gets empty but it is out of control for knockout to update DataTable anymore.
That's why when you click on `add families back` it gets added to view and then if you click on  `clear families` those added rows only will be removed. DataTable was already initialized for loading data.

**Solution**: You need to modify your model in a way that can update `DataTable` as well.
whenever you remove or add new item to you array you need to `re-draw` dataTable as well.

Assign a variable where you're initialing the table and either pass it as a `parameter` to your model or define it globally. Then inside your model whenever you remove or add a row update your `dataTable` as well.

```
var dt = $("#awesome-table").DataTable({"ordering": false});
```

---

```
 this.clearFamilies = function(){
      that.items.removeAll();
      // Update the table when All `items` array has been removed 
      dt.clear().draw();
      //Below will update the table whenever a single row is removed 
      // dt.row( rowIndexHere ).remove().draw();
 }
```

to add also you need to re-draw the table inside your model like :`dt.row.add( yourItemHere ).draw();`

**Alternative**: If your table does not have a large data (performance doesn't have a role) you can take advantage of `with` binding around your table and allow it to be re-rendered with the new bindings. [Check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15063794/can-cleannode-be-used-to-clean-binding/15069509#15069509)

I used a `with` binding which is set to `null` and then change that to the new data. This forces knockout to get rid of the DOM and automatically reapply the bindings when the with binding becomes `non-null`.

Details in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rz09djdq/5/) - Click on Add families and Remove families to see the magic happen :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick answer. I thought about adding rows using the table API but that will unfortunately not help as knockout won't see the new items and will therefore not bind to them.

Comment: Found a solution with your hints :) please see below and let me know what you think.

Comment: Awesome! Marked this one as the final answer :)