# Knockout component dispose not called

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, knockout-3.0

I have a custom KO component **address-input**

```
ko.components.register('address-input', {
    viewModel: { createViewModel: function ({}, componentInfo) {
        var self = {};
        self.dispose = function() {
            // When removed by KO, dispose computeds and subscriptions
        };

        return self;
    }},
    template: 'address-input'
});
```

The corresponding template is **address-input.html**

```
<div  class`enter code here`="clearfix row">
    <!-- elements come here -->
</div>
```

My application is an SPA one whose basic layout will be like below

A **main.html** will contain **section.html** which inturn holds **address-input,html**. On page nav , **section.html** will be replaced by another html and so on.

The section htmls are loaded through AJAX

```
        $j.ajax({
            url: url,
            success: function(htmlText) {
                var $el = $j(element);
                $el.html(htmlText);
                ko.applyBindingsToDescendants(bindingContext, $el[0]);
            },
            cache: false,
            mimeType: 'text/html-ko'
        });
```

I might have some observables subscribed in the address-input component in future. When that happens i would like the dispose method called when navigating away from the page. But it is not happening now. What is wrong here? Is it a case of DOM not getting removed from memory? If it is so , why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using jQuery to replace a part of the DOM tree. Knockout has no way of knowing which elements are removed and cannot call `dispose` on the bound models.

Use knockout's `html` binding to add/remove the new section or (not recommended) call `ko.cleanNode(element)` before calling `$el.html`.

An example that shows:

- When you manually remove a component from the DOM, knockout isn't notified and cannot call `dispose`
- When you use a regular binding to alter the DOM (e.g. `foreach`, `if`, `with`) knockout *does* call `dispose` when stuff has to be removed
- When you call `ko.cleanNode`, knockout detaches all nodes from their models, calls `dispose`, and let's you do what you want with the remaining DOM nodes.

```js
ko.components.register('mycomponent', {
    viewModel: function(params) {
      this.dispose = () => console.log("Dispose called");
    },
    template: "<li>My Component</li>"
});
 
// Some example data to render a list
const comps = ko.observableArray([1, 2, 3, 4]);

// Remove straigt from the DOM without knockout...
const badRemove = () => document
  .querySelector("mycomponent:last-child")
  .remove();
 
const manualDetach = () => ko.cleanNode(document.querySelector("div"));
  
// Use knockout to alter the DOM
const goodRemove = () => comps.shift();

ko.applyBindings({ comps, badRemove, goodRemove, manualDetach });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div data-bind="foreach: comps">
  <mycomponent></mycomponent>
</div>

<button data-bind="click: badRemove">bad remove</button>
<button data-bind="click: goodRemove">good remove</button>
<button data-bind="click: manualDetach">clean node</button>
```

Comment: Note that [`cleanNode` is undocumented and intended for internal use](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15069509/392102), so you probably shouldn't recommend it.