# How to remove knockoutjs bindings from entire dome

Tags: javascript, binding, knockout.js

I have built a page the uses knockout to due a plethora of things, and it works amazingly.

My problem comes in when a navigation occurs:
Page loads - works great
User navigates away - works great
User presses back button - original page breaks

It seems to me once the page is returned to using the back button the original binding still exists, and then the page downloads its data an calls ko.applyBinding, causing the bindings to then be applied twice breaking the page.

How do I remove the original binding, and I need the page to be bound to the newly downloaded data, and not the data that was available before navigation.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where in your code are you applying your bindings? `$(function() {}) // dom ready jquery` or just in a script tag at the bottom of the page, etc.  ?

Comment: yes I am using the jquery $(function(){});

Answer (score 0):

Here's one idea from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13459885/989516

```
ko.unapplyBindings = function ($node, remove) {
    // unbind events
    $node.find("*").each(function () {
        $(this).unbind();
    });

    // Remove KO subscriptions and references
    if (remove) {
        ko.removeNode($node[0]);
    } else {
        ko.cleanNode($node[0]);
    }
};
```

Comment: I did come across that code and try it out, but havent been able to get it to work right. keeps throwing "Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDocument> has no method 'find' " error

Comment: Probably because it's supposed be a jQuery wrapped node. That's where the find() method comes from. So maybe try calling like ko.unapplyBindings($('#container'), true), where 'container' is the id of some outer element who's contents are getting replaced. Or ko.unapplyBindings($(document), true)

Comment: Good tip, and it did seem to work partially, but the main issues are still occurring.

Comment: Does your viewmodel hang around in global (window) scope after the user navigates away? Or does your viewmodel contain any references to global objects? If so can you remove these so everything is local to the view that gets unloaded? Maybe try isolating it in a closure like `;(function() {
  var foo = 'bar';
}());`