# KnockOut binding breaks after moving DOM element

Tags: javascript, data-binding, knockout.js

I have a web app built on KO and for the most part it has been a god-sent. However, I have one very frustrating problem.

When I move an element with jQuery from one spot in the DOM to another, the bindings seem to randomly break. Sometimes they survive the move, sometimes they don't. Anyone know what might be causing this? I wish I could give a specific example, but I can't seem to re-create it in a simple case (for a fiddle) and it truly is random (3 in 10 tries).

Is there a way to refresh the bindings in an element?

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue. It was happening for me when I was moving the DOM element before applying bindings.

Make sure that all the applyBinding calls are made before you move the DOM element.

That is about all the help I can give without a code sample.

Comment: the bindings are applied right away when the page loads. The dom elements are moved by user action... there really is nothing to show in the code. Bindings all work perfectly, then I move it with jquery and one of the 5 bindings in the element just stops working. Can I re-applyBindings?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try using `ko.cleanNode` to clear the bindings from the moved element, then `ko.applyBindings( model, element )` to rebind them?

See also [How to clear/remove observable bindings in Knockout.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10048485/how-to-clear-remove-observable-bindings-in-knockout-js).