# Does jquery remove function also removes knockout bindings?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I have a div where I use knockout bindings. For example,

```
<div id='my_div'>
  <span data-bind="text: dialog_body"></span> 
</div>
```

So, the knockout binding is:

```
var viewmodel=function(){
 this.dialog_body = 'Some text';
};
ko.applyBindings(new viewmodel(),$("#my_div")[0]);
```

Now the question is: if I call `$('#my_div').remove();` will this also remove the knockout binding or should I be worried about memory leak?

Comment: jQuery does not know about KO and KO doesn't care about jQuery. See [cleanNode as discussed here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15063794/can-cleannode-be-used-to-clean-binding) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10048485/how-to-clear-remove-observable-bindings-in-knockout-js?lq=1). However, if you structure the DOM to be *only* modified from KO bindings (if/foreach/template/views-in-Durandal) on observables then everything should cleanup automatically.

Comment: Thanks, i could not make cleanNode work. Both the html and the viewmodel was dynamically generated by jquery-ui. So, I tried cleaning the node before binding, but it was throwing error if there was not a binding already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery has nothing to do with Knockout. It can remove nodes - but this won't clean up any bound KO observables. In the given case this will mean there is a *slight* memory leak as KO maintains data via an internal collection (see `ko.utils.domData`) after the node is simply removed with jQuery.

Two traditional methods used in KO to cleanup after itself are `cleanNode` and `removeNode` (however neither will remove bound events!) which should be used as needed .. using cleanNode (on a node bound via KO) is the *minimum* required to clean up data.

---

*However,* I don't think that this is a suitable place to manually clean up KO! The standard bindings will already handle cleanup, if used correctly.

Instead, write the code like the following. (See [Creating custom bindings that control descendant bindings](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings-controlling-descendant-bindings.html) for `withProperties`; you'll also have to [make it virtual-element compatible](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings-for-virtual-elements.html) to use it as below.)

```
<div id='my_div'>
  <!--ko 'if': someObservable-->
    <!--ko withProperties: { data: someObservable() }-->
      <span data-bind="text: data.dialog_body"></span> 
    <!--/ko-->
  <!--/ko-->
</div>
```

Then simply set the observable to something to create the node ..

```
someObservable(myVm)
```

.. or undefined to clear it ..

```
someObservable(undefined)
```

After all, one generally won't really `$('#my_div').remove()` but will rather `$('#my_div').dialog('close')`. Actually removing the node will work just as well, as long as the *same* element is added back later for the new dialog.

The `someObservable` value could come from the "root" view model - I recommend having a root view model! - or it could come from a window property, for those feeling hackish:

```
window.someObservable = ko.observable()
```

Comment: Having a global observable is not an option for me, as I am working in a very big project and global variable can screw up things. However, If I can get the current binding from an id, then I can change the observable on that binding. Perhaps,  `ko.dataFor` or `ko.contextFor` will help.

Comment: @faisal It sounds like the big project is in need of some love then! And I would *still* recommend the above approach - but making the observable part of the containing model. Have you looked at using [Durandal](http://durandaljs.com/)? It makes it easy to apply models to different "views". (And while it supports SPA, it need not be used as an SPA.)

Comment: Ok, i will take a look into Durandal. Thanks. I will experiment with it and let you know.

Comment: @faisal Using `cleanNode` will work fine, however, just make sure to only use it on bound nodes. You can check using `ko.contextFor` (it should return undefined for non-bound nodes) .. or just try/catch the exception if it's used on a non-bound node. Make sure to *remove the DOM events* separately.

Comment: I saw your edit. my_div is not originally part of the page, but later added by jquery-ui dialog, while adding, its contents was loaded from an external knockout template and then binded.

Comment: Cool, I will try out all of your suggestions, if I make any of them work for my project, I will accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to remove the span from the DOM. Simply modify your KO span to include a 'visible' binding for an observable boolean. Then, when you want to "hide" your span, simply set the boolean to false.

```
<span data-bind="text: dialog_body, visible: show_span"></span>
```

Then in your KO code, make your boolean observable:

```
var viewModel = { 
    show_span: ko.observable(true);
}
```

And when you are ready to hide the span:

```
viewModel.show_span(false);
```

Comment: My problem was more complex than the example I gave. I am trying to bind knockout templates on jquery-ui dialogs.