# Knockout.js's cleanNode does not unbind events

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a modal popup with similar data and need the bindings cleared. [The answer for the highest rating](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10049722/4126319) says to use knockout's clean node method

Here are (handwritten) code snippets:

```
var ViewModel = function(v) {
   var self = this;
   self.Foo = ko.observable(v.Foo);
   self.Bar = ko.observable(v.Bar);
   self.Stuffs = ko.observableArray([]);
   self.AddStuffs = function() { ... }
}

var myViewModel = new ViewModel({Foo : "", Bar: "" });
var myModal= document.getElementById("myModal");
ko.cleanNode(myModal);
ko.applyBindings(myViewModel, myModal);
```

html:

```
<div id="myModal">
<a href="#" data-bind="click:$root.AddStuff">my link</a>
<table>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach:Stuffs ">
        <tr>
            <td><span data-bind="text:Interval"></span></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

When I first open the modal, everything seems to work okay. But [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15069509/4126319) says cleanNode is the incorrect solution due to cleanNode being knockout's internal cleanup. It doesn't clean up event handlers, so when my modal is closed and opened again and I click the link for AddStuff, the event gets called n times (n = how many times I opened the popup). The proposed solution mentioned was "A better pattern is to use with or the template binding around a section and allow it to be re-rendered with the new bindings." but there was no followup on how to do either.

I'm not sure what he means by "template" but I [tried adding "with"](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/with-binding.html) to bind my div that I use for the modal and events are still being called multiple times on one link click. Can someone help me find a way to get this working right?

Comment: that should work . can you make me a fiddle on this so i can check that up . try keeping `<a href` outside div and try . cheers

Comment: Without the actual source it'll be hard to resolve the issue. I've used `cleanNode` in combination with jQuery dialog [destroy](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#method-destroy) to reuse dialogs. [An example](http://jsfiddle.net/e89wwjm7/1/) using jQuery dialog and a `with binding` isn't having the described issue. Edit in your attempt using the with binding.

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce it in fiddle because of another (related?) issue. [Here's what I have so far](http://jsfiddle.net/rn4d4gav/) . When you click close and then try to open the dialog again, I get "Uncaught Error: You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element." When I uncomment the "cleanNode(z) line, the dialog no longer shows up in jsfiddle. In the code I'm using, the dialog will show up, but clicking "my link" invokes the event twice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `cleanNode` is what you want.  Generally speaking, you shouldn't need to be cleaning nodes and reapplying bindings unless you're doing something very out of the ordinary, which I don't think you are.  You simply want to change the ViewModel that that particular section of the DOM is bound to, correct?

I'd simply make an observable that holds the ViewModel that the modal should be bound to, and then write your template based on that.

```
var ModalViewModel = function(v) {
   var self = this;
   self.Foo = ko.observable(v.Foo);
   self.Bar = ko.observable(v.Bar);
   self.Stuffs = ko.observableArray([]);
   self.AddStuffs = function() { ... }
}

var modalViewModel = new ModalViewModel({Foo : "Foo", Bar: "Bar" });

var viewModel = {
    modal: ko.observable(modalViewModel)
};

var myModal= document.getElementById("myModal");

ko.applyBindings(myViewModel, myModal);
```

Note that the viewModel that is actually bound to the modal never changes, but contains a sub-viewModel that does.  The above logic should be executed exactly once, then to change or remove the modal, the `viewModel.modal` observable can be modified.

Then your template would look like

```
<div id="myModal" data-bind="with: modal">
<a href="#" data-bind="click:AddStuff">my link</a>
<table>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach:Stuffs ">
        <tr>
            <td><span data-bind="text:Interval"></span></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

(With the only change being the `with: modal` part, and the removal of an unnecessary `$root`)

Here's a minimalistic version that demonstrates this working: http://jsfiddle.net/260wypyk/

Comment: I removed cleanNode and added the "with" binding along with the other changes you had but it's not working for me. When I click the link to open the modal, I'm getting an error like this: Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "value: function (){return Foo } (Foo is not defined). It was working before the "with" bind.

Comment: What does your logic for "opening the modal" look like?

Comment: it's similar to what I have in [the jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/rn4d4gav/) Perhaps I should note that I'm opening this dialog from a link in another dialog

Comment: I added a jsfiddle with a simple example of how it should work, that you should be able to adapt to your code.

Comment: An important key is you should do ko.applyBindings exactly once; rather than doing it in an event callback, like you're currently doing.

Comment: Thank you; Your last comment about doing ko.applyBindings from an event callback was my real problem. I'm pretty sad that I missed that...